# Reading ".dot" files in R with attribute information

Tags: r, igraph

How can one read in a .dot file representing a graph into R and include attribute information?

I can read in a .dot file using `sna::read.dot`. But this just returns an adjacency matrix without any of the attribute labels, as far as I can tell.

Using `igraph::write.graph`, I can write a file in the dot format...but `igraph::read.graph` does not allow dot files.

Comment: `Rgraphviz::agread` maybe

Answer (score 0):

If this was created by Graphviz then I suggest `agread()` from `Rgraphviz` provided by Bioconductor.

> ```
>  agwrite(graph, filename) 
>  agread(filename, layoutType="dot", layout=TRUE)
> ```

Related: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/48598/

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me. Is there variation in the dot format?

Comment: @CliffAB Could you provide the file or a small version of the file so that I can try some things?